# Using a variable across multiple files without declaring it with extern

Tags: c

I have an array of  `typedef struct Books Book` in a file1.h declared as `Book books[20]`. Now, I **initialise the array in file1.c** and then **use it in file2.c (that includes file1.h), without defining it**. The program works fine. But I don't understand why. Since I have not used extern with books, shouldn't I be getting a compile-time error (undefined reference) for file2.c?

file1.h

```
Book books[20];
```

file1.c:

```
#include file1.h
    void intializeBooks(){
    /**
    *Code to initialize book name and its cost
    */
    }
```

file2.c:

```
   #include "file1.h"
    void addOrder() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
                if (books[i].cost != -999) {
                    fprintf(fptr, "\t\t%d.%s\n", (i + 1),
                            books[i].name); //works correctly
                } else
                    break;
            }
```

Comment: How do you know it is the same `books` in each file?

Comment: By accessing the values. @ScottHunter

Comment: You need to show the code. See [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean "without defining it"?  You have a definition (not a declaration) in file1.h, which is included in file2.c.  The definition is therefore included in file2.c

Comment: @WilliamPursell Isn't books extern by default?

Comment: @WilliamPursell: It's a [tentative definition](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/extern).

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/634919 under "Not so good way" for an explanation of what is going on here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use extern to share variables between source files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files)

Comment: In short, you have defined global objects with the same name in both `file1.c` and `file2.c` (since they both include the tentative definition from `file1.h`).  This is undefined behavior according to the C standard, but some implementations handle it by merging both objects into one, which sounds like what you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A global declaration without an initializer constitutes a "tentative definition":

[6.9.2p2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.9.2p2):

> A declaration of an identifier for an object that has file scope
>   without an initializer, and without a storage-class specifier or with
>   the storage-class specifier static, constitutes a tentative
>   definition. If a translation unit contains one or more tentative
>   definitions for an identifier, and the translation unit contains no
>   external definition for that identifier, then the behavior is exactly
>   as if the translation unit contains a file scope declaration of that
>   identifier, with the composite type as of the end of the translation
>   unit, with an initializer equal to 0.

Basically, tentative definitions serve as declarations that become a definition unless it is overridden by an actual definition.

The standard guarantees that this'll work in just one translation unit: i.e., what you are doing with the `Books` variable being tentative in several translation unit is not guaranteed to work. However, practically it does work since common linkers (upcoming pun intended) use a special symbol type called a "common symbol" for symbols that were still tentative at the end of a translation unit, and with that special symbol type. tentative definitions work even across several translation units. (If there's one non-tentative definition, it overrides all the other ones; otherwise the tentative definitions get merged into just one zero-initialized external definition.)

Long story short, if you want to be perfectly standard compliant, you should replace the tentative definition in the header with a proper `extern` declaration. If you don't, your code might still work. (On Unix-based platforms, it probably will work because common symbols are a feature that's very old, even though it's nonstandard feature.) Either way it's bad practice to put tentative definitions in header files.